# How to fill BOTH and CENTER a panel with GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

guys! How can I place the chairs correctly? In the second frame of the image below I have posted I have drawn circles where I want to put those objects.
[image]

I have used 4 BorderLayouts to place the labels and the images in order not to complicate the gridbaglayout too much and then I added them to the gridbaglayout like this:

```
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH/*PAGE_START*/;
    c.weightx = 10; 
    c.weighty = 10; 
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(topPlayerPanel, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(leftPlayerPanel, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(t, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(rightPlayerPanel, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(bottomPlayerPanel, c);
```

If I place them with PAGE_START, LINE_START, LINE_END, PAGE_END, the placement is correct. But it doesn't show me the whole image :(

Comment: To get answers sooner, post [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use invisible components that take up excess space with `GridBagLayout` and "push" other components around. I use [`Box.Filler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.Filler.html) to push those computer icons to the table panel.

[image: table with chairs]

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class GBLTableWithChairs extends JFrame {

    public GBLTableWithChairs() {
        setTitle("Table with chairs");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc;
        Box.Filler filler;
        JLabel label;

        JPanel table = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.GRAY));
        table.add(new JLabel("<html>TABLE&nbsp;TABLE<br/>TABLE&nbsp;TABLE<br/>TABLE&nbsp;TABLE"));
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(table, gbc); // to frame

        JPanel leftChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        filler = createHorizontalFiller();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
        leftChair.add(filler, gbc); // to leftChair
        label = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon"));
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        leftChair.add(label, gbc); // to leftChair
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(leftChair, gbc); // to frame

        JPanel topChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        filler = createVerticalFiller();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0d;
        topChair.add(filler, gbc); // to topChair
        label = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon"));
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        topChair.add(label, gbc); // to topChair
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(topChair, gbc); // to frame

        JPanel rightChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        filler = createHorizontalFiller();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
        rightChair.add(filler, gbc); // to rightChair
        label = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon"));
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        rightChair.add(label, gbc); // to rightChair
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(rightChair, gbc); // to frame

        JPanel bottomChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        filler = createVerticalFiller();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0d;
        bottomChair.add(filler, gbc); // to bottomChair
        label = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon"));
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        bottomChair.add(label, gbc); // to bottomChair
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(bottomChair, gbc); // to frame

        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private Box.Filler createHorizontalFiller() {
        return new Box.Filler(new Dimension(0, 0), new Dimension(0, 0), new Dimension(32767, 0));
    }

    private Box.Filler createVerticalFiller() {
        return new Box.Filler(new Dimension(0, 0), new Dimension(0, 0), new Dimension(0, 32767));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GBLTableWithChairs().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really! But I've got another issue... I added more detail below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I rewrited my code using the fillers, but I've got this issue:

[image]

For example for the left chair, I place the filler and then the leftChairPanel (it conists of a BorderLayout with a JLabel in BorderLayout.NORTH, and the Image in BorderLayout.CENTER), but I get this... maybe I did use the wrong GridBagConstraints fill?

```
JPanel table = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    table.add(t);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(table, gbc);

    JPanel leftChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    filler = createHorizontalFiller();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
    leftChair.add(filler, gbc); //alla sedia di sinistra
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    leftChair.add(leftPlayerPanel, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(leftChair, gbc); //al mainPanel

    JPanel topChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    filler = createVerticalFiller();
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0d;
    topChair.add(filler, gbc); //alla sedia in alto
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    topChair.add(topPlayerPanel, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(topChair, gbc); //al panel

    JPanel rightChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    filler = createHorizontalFiller();
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
    rightChair.add(filler, gbc); //alla sedia di destra
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    rightChair.add(rightPlayerPanel, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(rightChair, gbc); //al panel

    JPanel bottomChair = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    filler = createVerticalFiller();
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0d;
    bottomChair.add(filler, gbc); //alla sedia in basso
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    bottomChair.add(bottomPlayerPanel, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(bottomChair, gbc); //al panel
```